# N-Tier architecture and redundant database accesses

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, architecture, n-tier-architecture

As a part of my master thesis I am going to develop a software for heat optimization in apartments. This software will we middle-sized and will have a web based interface towards customers and an interface towards sensors (which is placed in the apartment). I'm considering a multi-tier architecture. Many of the objects in the system will have its own database table. This means lots and lots of code and SQL statements (and time) for saving and retrieving the objects. Is this the standard way of developing software still?

I have considered to use NHibernate but I have som doubts, the primary reasons are:
I do not have much experience in software development.

The session handling seems quite complex, especially if one must have a businesslayer providing functionality to both a webinterface and to a sensor interface. Because of the lazy loading I need to have the session active at these interfaces but then the presentation layer is aware of the data acess layer which is not desireable.

So, is there any alternatives? I am using MySql 5.5 and C#.

Comment: How many apartments?  How many sensors in each apartment?

Comment: Not clear yet. Perhaps around 100 at the testing phase but the system must be scalable up to a much bigger size. Each apartment will have at least one sensor in each room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current orthodoxy in web development is [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller); in Microsoft land, that means [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). The MS site has a great tutorial describing the way you integrate your "model" classes, representing your business domain, with a database.

ASP.Net MVC also provides a way of building a Web API - this should allow your sensors to communicate with the application using the same underlying model classes.

Comment: The problem is that the application is not primarily a web application. It will contain a heavy optimization algorithm. The web part is only for displaying information to the customers such as a log of their apartment temperature. This is why I am considering a n-tier architecture. So that both the web, the optimization algorithm (which is a part of the business logic) and the communication with the sensors can use the same underlying logic and database (to reduce the amount of code and increase the maintainability of the system).

Comment: That's sorta the point of MVC - by abstracting a "model" layer, you can centralize your business logic into a domain model, and have multiple ways of interacting with it by adding specific views and/or controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have an inherent logical partition that should lead to an abstraction of the sensor-database communication into one layer, and the customer-database communication into another layer. The sensor-side could provide a read-only set of interface(s) to provide information (as needed) to the customer side, while the core functionality for your heat optimization work can reside essentially in the middle.

If you spend some time thinking about how these pieces should be partitioned, allowing you to define clean interfaces between the two, the complexity of the overall project should diminish at least some.

Answer (score 0):

I would carefully consider NHibernate if you "I do not have much experience in software development." While it is an amazing tool and extremely powerful - the learning curve can be steep and depends how much time you want to commit to learning it. Having said that however, I am really happy with it.